# My If Statements in Python are not working

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to python and I am writing a program to play Rock, Paper, Scissor. When I start to do the if else statements to compare outputs from user and the computer, my program just completely skips the if-else statements. Not sure what's going on with it.

```
user = input("Please enter Rock, Paper, Scissor: ")
while user not in ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissor"):
      print("Try again")
      user = input("Please enter Rock, Paper, Scissor: ")


if user == "Rock":
   print("Your Choice is Rock")
elif user == "Scissor":
   print("Your Choice is Scissor")
elif user == "Paper":
   print("Your Choice is Paper")


import random
AI=["Rock", "Paper", "Scissor"]
b=random.randint(0,2)
print("The computer choice is " + AI[b])

if user == b:
   print("Tie")
elif user == "Rock":
   if b == "Scissor":
      print("Rock Beats Scissor")
```

It goes through all of the code expect the last if-else statement. It just finishes the program after the computer chooses what to use.

Comment: `user == b` will compare e.g. `"Rock"` to `2`, and that is indeed always false. You instead want `user == AI[b]`

Comment: What exactly gets skipped? `user == b`, by the way, will never be true, because `user` is a `str` and `b` is an `int`.

Comment: It's a bit roundabout to randomly generate an integer that represents the AI's choice. Consider generating the choice directly using `random.choice`.

Comment: Thank You guys! I totally forgot that b is equal to an Int. I did AI[b] mentioned earlier and it worked out perfectly.

Comment: if something doesn't work then use `print()` to see values in variables - it helps to see mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the last `if`, you are comparing a string with a integer `user == b` remember that the user choice is a string but `b` is a random number between 0 and 2.

```
if user == AI[b]:  # you need to compare the value with the string selection of the "AI"
   print("Tie")
elif user == "Rock":
   if AI[b] == "Scissor":
      print("Rock Beats Scissor")
else:
   # I don't remember what are the rules to win or lose LOL, but I guess there are more
   # maybe you need more conditions
   print("other choice...")
```

Comment: same for `b == "Scissor"`

Comment: Or change the `b=random.randint(0,2)` to `b = random.choice(AI)`. Now `b` is the actual string.